# Excel VBA code to take screenshot and paste save in word and save in local drive

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a screenshot of a desktop at frequent intervals and would like to save the same word doc to local drive without overriding. Below is the code which is working fine when until the screenshot in the word doc. But it's throwing error while trying to save the file.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan 
As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44
Private Const VK_LCONTROL As Long = &HA2
Private Const VK_V = &H56
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Sub Sample()
Dim savePath As String
Dim i As Integer

Sleep 3000
DoEvents

'~~> Take a snapshot
Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)

'~~> Start Word

Set wordobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = wordobj.Documents.Add

wordobj.Visible = True

Set objSelection = wordobj.Selection

'Paste into Word
 objSelection.Paste
 objDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Email\Screenshot.docx")


 On Error Resume Next
TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
On Error GoTo 0

 'Determine if File exists
 If TestStr = "" Then
 FileExist = False
  Else
  FileExist = True
 End If

i = 0
savePath = "C:\Email\Screenshot.docx"

While (FileExist(savePath))
savePath = savePath + i
i= i + 1
Wend

objDoc.SaveAs (savePath)
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try save your file, you miss file name replace this :

```
objDoc.SaveAs ("D:\")
```

with this for example :

```
objDoc.SaveAs ("D:\filename.docx")
```

To prevent file exist :

```
Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean

Dim TestStr As String

  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if File exists
  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If

End Function
```

And in your save method :

```
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim i As integer

    i = 0
    savePath = "D:\filename"

    While ( FileExist(savePath)) 
        savePath = savePath + i;
        i++;
   Wend

    objDoc.SaveAs(savePath)
```

For example, if your file exist this will increment and add a number in filename

Comment: Thank you, Leo, but I am still getting the error.

"Word cannot save or create this file. Make sure that the disk you want to save the file on Is not full, write-protected, or damaged."

Comment: Still same error ? strange because it's work for me, however be careful if your file already exist, there will be an error if you try to save with same filenae

Comment: Yes, I do have read/write permission. How to save file without overriding the existing file

Comment: Hi Leo, I have updated the codes but the file is not incrementing. its throwing error on i++. Please help

Comment: replace with : i = i + 1

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I have updated my codes with i=i+1, but its throwing below error.
"Word cannot save this file because it is already open elsewhere.